# C# Multiple SelectionChanged Events

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, selectionchanged

I want to have 2 selectionchanged events,
like this

```
protected override void xpathList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
//my code
}

private void xpathList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventsArgs e)
{
//my code
}
```

it gives the following error: `Type 'TestApp.MainPage' already defines a member called 'xpathList_SelectionChanged' with the same parameter type`.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create to identical method with same signature.
If you want to handle one event for one control by two different methods, you must use such code:

```
Page_Init()
{
    //initialization code
    xpathList.OnSelectionChanged += xpathList_SelectionChanged1;
    xpathList.OnSelectionChanged += xpathList_SelectionChanged2;
}

protected void xpathList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
//my code
}

protected void xpathList_SelectionChanged2(object sender, SelectionChangedEventsArgs e)
{
//my code
}
```

and remove event handler declaration from markup.

[How to: Create Event Handlers in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w2tb12s.aspx)

Comment: what is the event handler, and also i get this errror code `TestApp.MainPage.xpathList_SelectionChanged2(object, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs)': no suitable method found to override`

Comment: @Lark125 Event hadler - method to handle the `SelectionChanged` event.  Updated my answer to use the `override` keyword.

Comment: thank you verry much one thing it can't find the method `OnSelectionChanged` it can find `SelectionChanged`

Comment: @Lark125 Oh, I think this is my error. Use `SelectionChenged` event.

Comment: only one thing i just got one problem at `protected override void` i get no `suitable method found to override`

Comment: Try to remove the `override` - this is not needed to event handler.

Comment: i only got one selectionchanged working, what do i have to say in the xaml file at  `selectiongchanged=""` i got `selectionchanged="xpathList_SelectionChanged"` and that is the only one that worsk the one that is cald `xpathList_SelectionChanged` the one `xpathList_SelectionChanged2` doesn't work

Comment: @Lark125 Remove it from markup, as I said. You don't to initialize it there, if you use codebehind.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two methods with different names.

You'll need to add the second one as a handler manually; the designer can't add two handlers to one event.
Write `xpathList.SelectionChanged += SomeMethod`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just bind two functions to one even?

```
XPathList xpathList = new XPathList();
xpathList.OnSelectionChanged +=(s,e) => FirstHandler(s,e);
xpathList.OnSelectionChanged += (s,e) => SecondHandler(s,e);
```

Comment: Why do you use `new XPathList()`?

Comment: Yep, my bad, should be List of XPath'es:
`List<XPath>()`

Comment: No, why are you creating new control?

Comment: Why do you use lambdas here? `xpathList.SelectionChanged += FirstHandler;` works just as well.

Comment: @VMAtm That wasn't so obvious to me (according to question code), so I've created `SomeObject` before operating with it (e.g. binding handlers to events). If it would be already defined, I've just used it.